# Inserting Array into PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, insert, element

Working with an array file with following structure. I know there are additional arrays that need to be inserted under each array 'color'.

```
 $items=array (
   0 => 
  array (
    'color' => 'category_a',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'book' => 'Gone With The Wind',
    'movie' => 'GWTW',
    'id'=> 'A100'
  ),

  2 => 
  array (
    'book' => 'Goldfinger',
    'movie' => 'GF',
    'id'=> 'A103'
  ),
   3 => 
  array (
    'color' => 'category_b',
  ),

  4 => 
  array (
    'book' => 'Across The Great Dvide',
    'movie' => 'ATGD',
    'id'=> 'B102'
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'book' => 'Goldfinger',
    'movie' => 'GF',
    'id'=> 'B103'
  ),
  );
```

Once this array is created, I am using a list to loop thru to verify that each value in the list is placed in each 'color' array as follows

```
  foreach ($controllist as $key=>$value){
    foreach($items as $item){
      if(in_array($value['book'],$item){
            echo "PRESENT IN ARRAY"."<BR>";
      }else{
             echo "INSERT INTO ARRAY HERE"."<BR>";
      }
     }
     }
```

For simplicity my controllist looks like
Gone With The wind
Across The Great Divide
Goldfinger
Once complete I should end up with the info for Across The Great Divide inserted into 'color'=> 'category a' as the [2] with Goldfinger moving down one. In 'color'=>category_b' the first array should be Gone With The Wind. Any of the 'color' arrays could be missing an array at any position. To sum it up, need to check for the existence of a value from the list, if not present insert into the array. Other than using the foreach loops shown is there an easier way of doing this? If not how can I get the information inserted into the proper position?
Thanks

EDIT:
I believe the question may not be clear. What I need to do is check for the existence of one array in another. If the value in conrollist is not present in the array, insert an array into the array according the position in the conrollist. The inserted array will have the same structure as the others (I can take care of this part). I am having trouble determining if it exist and if not inserting it. Hope this helps

Comment: off topic, have you considered using a database instead? anyway, why not put the category data along with those book and movie and id etc.

Comment: Not sure I follow your off topic. It is basically check for the existence of an array and if not present inserting it into the array.

Comment: Brother, your question is really unclear.

Comment: I don't feel like your question is very clear. From what I am reading, it seems like you really want to work with a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to be using a `for` loop instead so you have a pointer on each iteration in order to determine where you are in the array.

```
foreach($items as $item){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($controllist); $i++) {
        if(in_array($controllist[$i]['book'],$item){
            echo "PRESENT IN ARRAY AT POS ".$i."<BR>";
        }else{
            $controllist[$i]['book'] = $yourvar;
            echo "INSERT INTO ARRAY HERE"."<BR>";
        }
    }
}
```